# Migrate Data From Amazon Redshift to Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds

I was asked for a solution to migrate data from Redshift to an RDS instance.

The migration will consist in only few tables and i'm trying to migrate them to a postgresql instance.

Any clue where could I begin?

Comment: How much data do you have? (Number of tables, rows, storage?) Is Redshift using any User-Defined Functions or Stored Procedures? To which RDS engine are you moving (PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc)? Feel free to Edit your question to add this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options to do it. Which one suits best to you depends on many questions answer like-- size of the data, one time or regular process and so on and so forth...

Typical process to do it.

1. Select and Export the data
2. Temporary hold and transfer data from import will be triggered to EC2/Any Machine
3. Load the data

Here goes options-

1. For step 1, you have multiple options but best option could be use Copy command and export 3 using a copy command.
2. For step 2, Multiple options like store on local/ec2/S3/... I think best option could be s3 and its done in step-1 I suggested.
3. For step 3, depends on RDS type but most of database supports way to import data from CSV, so use that.

If its `Redshift` to `mysql`. You may would like to refer steps, I have suggested on one of [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926048/amazon-redshift-to-mysql-using-pentaho-data-integration/49791096#49791096) earlier.

I hope it will help. Feel free if you have specific additional questions.